# How to prove that $n\log n = O(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics, proof-writing

How to prove that $n\log n = O(n^2)$?

I think I have the idea but need some help following through.

I start by proving that if $f(n) = n \log n$ then $f(n)$ is a member of $O(n\log n)$. To show this I take a large value $k$ and show that $i\geq k$ and $f(i) \leq c_1\cdot i\log(i)$.

Next I need to show that if $f(n)$ is a member of $O(n \log n)$ then $f(n)$ is a member of $O(n^2)$ by taking a large value $k$ and showing that $i\geq k$ and $f(i) \leq c_2\cdot i\log i$ which turns out to be $f(i)=i^2\log i$ which is a member of $O(n^2)$.

Is that right? Could someone formalize this for me?

Comment: You spend a lot of time on the not relevant $n\log n$ is a member of $O(n\log n)$. What is written there is worrisome. To show this (not needed) fact, you need to show that there is a $C$ and an $N$ such that $n\log n\le C(n\log n)$ for $n\ge N$. This is trivially true with $C=1$ and $N=1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From your notation, it looks like we are assuming that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In fact, I'll be more general and just say $n\in(0,\infty)$.

Then $\log n<n$, since $n < 1+n < e^n$ by its Taylor series.

Thus, $n\log n<n^2$ for all $n\in(0,\infty)$.

As a consequence, $n\log n = O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Prove that $n\log n =O(n^2)$ is equivalent to prove that the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\log n}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}$$ is finite
which is the case by simple applying the l'Hôpital theorem to find that the desired limit is $0$.

**Remark** Since this limit is $0$ we have precisely
$$n\log n= o(n^2)\quad \text{little o}$$

Comment: Not "equivalent," since it is possible this limits doesn't exist but there is an $O()$ relationship. If the limit exists, then the statements are equivalent, however. It's really equivalent to $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n}$ being finite.

Comment: I mean it's equivalent in the example given by the OP but yes in general case there's no equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\frac{n\log n}{n^2}=\frac{\log n}n\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital, for ex.}}{\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0}$$

Answer (score 1):

You only have to prove the first part. When you write $f = O(g)$ you really mean $f \in O(g)$. To prove that first part you should show that
$$
  \limsup \frac fg < +\infty
$$
and in this case you actually have
$$
\lim \frac fg = 0
$$
hence the condition is satisfied.

Comment: "You really mean..." Depends on the notation used by the class. Not clear if that set theory notation is really useful if their classwork doesn't cover it...

Comment: The equality sign has only one meaning, which is an equivalence relation. So $f=O(g)$ is simply a *wrong* notation or an abuse of notation.

Comment: Technically, true, but a lot of people learn the big $O$ notation without knowing set membership notation.  As for "equality sign has only one meaning," I'd suggest that this is not really true - we abuse equality all the time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the formal definition of big-O, we have to show:
$$\exists c,{n_0} > 0,\;\;\forall n \ge {n_0} \to n\log n \le c.{n^2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaey4aIqIaam
% 4yaiaacYcacaWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyOpa4JaaGim
% aiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjbVlabgcGiIiaad6gacqGHLjYScaWGUbWaaS
% baaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyOKH4QaamOBaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4z
% aiaad6gacqGHKjYOcaWGJbGaaiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaik
% daaaaaaa!50F9!
$$
Lets start:
$$\begin{array}{l}n\log n \le c.{n^2}\\ \div n \to \log n \le c.n\\Let\;c = 1 \to \log n \le n\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaWGUb
% GaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaadogacaGGUaGaamOB
% amaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiabgEpa4kaad6gacqGHsgIRci
% GGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbGaeyizImQaam4yaiaac6cacaWGUbaa
% baGaamitaiaadwgacaWG0bGaaGjbVlaadogacqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaey
% OKH4QaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgsMiJkaad6gaaaaa!5C38!
$$
On the other hand, according to the function diagrams, we know:
$$\log n < n\;\;;\;for\;any\;n > 0 \to we\;choose\;{n_0} = 1\;optionally.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgYda8iaad6gacaaMe8UaaGjbVlaacUdacaaM
% e8UaamOzaiaad+gacaWGYbGaaGjbVlaadggacaWGUbGaamyEaiaays
% W7caWGUbGaeyOpa4JaaGimaiabgkziUkaadEhacaWGLbGaaGjbVlaa
% dogacaWGObGaam4Baiaad+gacaWGZbGaamyzaiaaysW7caWGUbWaaS
% baaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaaGymaiaaysW7caWGVbaeaaaa
% aaaaa8qacaWGWbGaamiDaiaadMgacaWGVbGaamOBaiaadggacaWGSb
% GaamiBaiaadMhacaGGUaaaaa!688B!
$$
So, we proved:
$$c = {n_0} = 1 \to \exists c,{n_0} > 0,\;\;\forall n \ge 1 \to n\log n \le c.{n^2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam4yaiabg2
% da9iaad6gadaWgaaWcbaGaaGimaaqabaGccqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaeyOK
% H4Qaey4aIqIaam4yaiaacYcacaWGUbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaicdaaeqaaO
% GaeyOpa4JaaGimaiaacYcacaaMe8UaaGjbVlabgcGiIiaad6gacqGH
% LjYScaaIXaGaeyOKH4QaamOBaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaad6gacq
% GHKjYOcaWGJbGaaiOlaiaad6gadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaaaa!5750!
$$